# Django ListView derived classes ignoring paginate_by field

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 3.2

I am using OOP to keep my code DRY. I have a base class Foo (which derives from ListView), and I am setting common properties in that class.

I then have two specialisations of Foo - which I expect to be cognisant of the `paginate_by` member variable - however, the subclasses seem to be ignoring the variable I set `paginate_by` to, as it has no effect.

This is my code:

```
class UserFooList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    paginate_by = 2


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # some processing logic

        return render(request, '/path/to/Foo_list.html', context=context, status=status_code)


    
class UserApprovedFooList(UserFooList):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.prefetch_related().filter(/* query criteria one */)

 

class UserFoosInModerationQueueList(UserFooList):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.prefetch_related().filter(/* query criteria two */)
```

Why is the `paginate_by` field being ignored by `UserApprovedFooList` and `UserFoosInModerationQueueList` - and how do I resolve this?

Comment: I've just reproduced this locally for myself, the child class was able to inherit with no problem. Is there a possibility that your child function `get_queryset` just returns less than the expected?

Comment: @Lewis in `UserFoosInModerationQueueList`, the logic is more complicated, and it can return an empty list (not a QuerySet). I don't know if this is significant - in any case, in my use cases, a non empty QuerySet is being returned.

Comment: Ah In that case, If feel the issue may stem from this logic. From the information provided in the question the code should work. I'd suggest starting by evaluating the class variable `paginate_by` right before `render()` is called to see if it's been manipulated by the logic.